# Azure DevOps API - Query Package Metrics returns BadRequest

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to make a API call

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/query-package-metrics?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0

It says the payload takes a string array of package ids. What exactly are the IDs? I made this call [Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0) which has IDs for the packages and got the one I need (I believe).

Using C#, I made this call after getting that ID from the previous call.

```
// Make call
var payload = new string[] { "some guid ID" };

var response = await client.PostAsync("/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?api-version=6.0-preview.1", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload)), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

The response returns BadRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The response returns BadRequest

The cause of the issue is that the json payload content has issue.

We can add the following json payload sample to the Rest API Request Body:

```
{"packageids":["PackageID1","PackageID2"]}
```

We can get the packages IDs with the Rest API: [Artifact Details - Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0)

We can get the ID value in the Rest API response.

**Updated:**

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packagemetricsbatch?api-version=6.0-preview.1");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic Base64PAT");
var content = new StringContent("{\"packageids\":[\"88d21b03-de05-4d64-bf10-c15735d1abb6\",\"9cf8e392-84d0-4417-bdf9-482bb34e68a2\"]}", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: I've made this call and this also returns a BadRequest

Comment: Have you check the json payload content? You can add breakpoints to check if the payload is in the correct format

Comment: I've copied and pasted your json example above and change `PackageID1` to what my ID for the package is (which is a GUID). Payload is now `{"packageids":["My GUID"]}`

Comment: In this case, the issue still exists, right?

Comment: Yes and I'm not sure why. I get the [id from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0#package) and make the call and it seems to return BadRequest

Comment: The id should be correct. Are you using the Azure devops service or azure devops server? If you are using service,, You can check the API URL GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?api-version=7.2-preview.1 You can try to change the api version

Comment: On the other hand, you can try to run the API from postman and check if it can work first

Comment: I'm using Azure DevOps Server. Also note that if a feed is set at an organization level (which mine is), the {project} can be excluded from the url.

Comment: It is a GET request which I did not need postman but just pasted the endpoint in my browser and it returns a result

Comment: POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packagemetricsbatch?api-version=6.0-preview.1 This rest api is a post request. I mean that you can try to run this api from postman with the request body

Comment: In this case, we can make sure that if the body and url are correct

Comment: Due to company policy, I cannot use Postman unfortunetly. I am working in C# and my PAT and HttpClient are setup correctly. I've tried this `POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packagemetricsbatch?api-version=6.0-preview.1` and it will not work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @HelloWorld Since you are using HttpClient, can you try the sample in the updated answer and check if it can work?

Comment: @HelloWorld Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the sample in the updated answer can work for you.

Comment: For some reason, your code did work. I'm not sure how they differ in reality.